# Outlook 2007 plugin failing to load (incorrect runtime)

Tags: .net, vsto, outlook-addin, office-2007

I have created an Outlook 2007 plugin which I have managed to install on Windows 7 using a setup project in Visual Studio 2010. It has worked fine on every Windows 7 machine I have installed it on. I had previously installed it successfully on two XP machines as well but I am having problems with one XP instance which is on a virtual machine.

AddInSpy shows that this addin failed to be loaded by Outlook because it couldn't load one of it's dependencies:

```
Add-in DLL path is not found. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\blah\blah\MyAddIn.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
```

I build a stripped down Addin which simply pops up a message box saying it started so that I new it wasn't any of the other dependencies my plugin relies on, and I get the same error message.

i suspect the 'This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.' Is the culprit, as later in the error log produced by AddInSpy i get:

```
Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
...
Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config
```

I have installed .NET 4 client profile (which the plugin is built to use) and extended on this machine and yet according to the logs it is trying to use .NET 2. I've also installed VSTO2010 runtime and the Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies.

So i guess my questions are:
Why is it trying to use .NET2?
how do i make it use .NET4?
and how can I ensure my installer makes it use the correct version?

Answer (score 3):

> This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime

That's the core error message.  You are doing battle with *another* plugin that's being loaded into Outlook and you lost the race.  It was first and it loaded the version 2 CLR.  Your addin can only work with the version 4 CLR.

One fix is to remove that add-in.  Another is to *force* Outlook to always load the version 4 CLR.  Which has a feature that version 2 doesn't have, it permits more than one CLR getting loaded.  Forcing this requires a outlook.exe.config file in the Office directory.  There might already be one (not sure) so edit the existing one if you find it.  It needs to contain these entries:

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. @Hans Passant: I tried to create an _outlook.exe.config_ file and placed it in the same directory as the outlook.exe and _outlook.exe.manifest_ which is the office12 directory. I still get the same problem. I set the LoadBehavior to 3 in the registry each time because when I try to open Outlook it sets it back to 2.

Comment: log says:
`LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Setup1\TestAddIn.dll
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/AddInSpy/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This is an inspection only bind.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft/Setup1/TestAddIn.dll.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8013101b). Probing terminated.`

Comment: Host: Outlook, 
Running: FALSE, 
Loaded: FALSE, 
Type: VSTO, 
FriendlyName: A test addin friendly name, 
ProgID: MyTestAddin, 
CLSID:  n/a, 
Manifest: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Setup1\TestAddIn.vsto|vstolocal, 
DllPath: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Setup1\TestAddIn.dll, 
LoadBehavior: 3, 
RegHive: HKCU, 
AssemblyName: ?, 
CLR_version: ?, 
Exposed: FALSE, 
Interfaces: ?, 
FormRegions: ?, 
VSTOR:  2008, 
Installed: ?, 
PubVer: n/a, 
Status: Alert

Comment: LOG: No application configuration file found.

Comment: Yeah, but that i didn't think that was a necessity. It says using the machine.config which is defaulted to when other configs don't exist. It's looking in the folder for .NET 2.0.50727 though.

Comment: Using machine.config and breaking every .NET 2 and 3.x program sounds like an excessively bad idea.  I can well imagine that the CLR actively prevents this.  Please do what I recommended.